Use dynamic database name in a stored procedure
I'm trying to create a SQL query to dynamically change database name passed in as @name variable, when trying to execute the stored procedure, I get an error message.
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [schema].[procname]
    (@name varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = N'SELECT ID, Name, [col1], [col2]
                 FROM @name.[schema].[table]';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO

EXEC [schema].[procname] 'DVMTIONAPP'

I get this error:

Must declare the scalar variable "@name".


What is your SQL Server version?

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126)

Finding dupes that don't suffer from injection is hard (the canonical is not a good choice); I found a couple quickly, but there's a lot with injection.

Side note, the correct data type for an object name is sysname (a synonym for nvarchar(128) NOT NULL).

SQL Server won't automatically replace the @name placeholder (inside a string) with the content of the variable.
You have to explicitly concatenate the strings. For avoiding code injection, you should use QUOTENAME().
Something like:
SET @sql = N'SELECT ID, Name, [col1], [col2]
                 FROM ' + QUOTENAME (@name) + N'.[schema].[table]';

For more complex cases, in which you're passing a multipart identifier ("DB.TABLE", etc), you could use DB_ID(), DB_NAME(), OBJECT_ID(), OBJECT_NAME(), etc.
For non-entities (like values in a WHERE clause, etc), in dynamic SQL, again avoiding injection, parameters are the way to go.

Please try the following solution.
SQL
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [schema].[procname]
( @name sysname )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = FORMATMESSAGE(N'SELECT ID, Name, [col1], [col2]
        FROM %s.[schema].[table];'
        , QUOTENAME(@name));

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO


this does not work.

Are you getting any errors? You can add PRINT @sql; line to the SP to see what is emitted.
